# Using MVC 3, Recommendation for creating Menus, HTML5, JQuery or 3rd Party Components?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am just trying to streamline my MVC3 development approach. I use Razor in the View and was wondering what the recommendation is for easily creating more fancy UI widgets such as Menus. I would hope I could leverage some good open source components and plug them in. I do subscribe to a good 3rd party component library, but wonder whether this type of feature is best implemented via JQuery UI or old style HTML/CSS?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, Stack Overflow isn't here to recommend tools for you.  However, I will say that whether to choose a javascript tool or straight html/css depends on the needs.

It's best to work with the simplest solution that solves your problem.  CSS can do menus quite well, and straight CSS menus are often the best choice.  However, if you need things straight css can't do, then you need to add javascript.  For instance, one problem with CSS menus is that it's very easy to "roll off" the menu and have it disappear from under your pointer.  Most javascript menus add a delay that allows you to roll off for a second and get back before the menu disappears.  This improves usability.

Even lots of fancy effects can be done strictly in CSS, but as with many such things.. it won't be compatible across all browsers, which is again where javascript comes into play.  Sometimes the only way to be compatible across the board is with js (at least without losing functionality).

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I think my interest here is what approach MVC developers are taking. With Razor, I can certainly appreciate the simple CSS approach. At the end of the day one needs good HTML/CSS to produce an appealing web site UI design anyway.

Comment: @EdB - That's just it... with MVC you don't need to worry about what MVC developers are doing.  MVC is only about the server side.  The client side (with the exception of validation and ajax methods) is all the same as if you were just writing straight html code.  So, anything you would do in straight html is what you would do in MVC

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recreate the wheel on this one, since so many web sites already do this. If you are trying to streamline your development, I'd say use your 3rd party library or find a good jQuery plugin. You could probably easily create your own in HTML/CSS/Jquery, but it will add on to your testing later. An existing 3rd party/jQuery type of component would take significantly less time and have a lot of features you want already built in.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.JQuery is so important that I need to get into it sooner rather than later. Interesting point about better compatibility with JS, although JS can be switched off in the browser. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [MVC SiteMap Provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider) in conjecuyion with a JavaScript menu of choice e.g. SuperFish http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/. The menu fancy JS part part is the least important.

From the MVC point of view what I think really matters is how you manage and maintain your menu. MVC SiteMap Provider makes it really easy to build an maintain menus (can even use Attributes to make Actions appear on the menu). It can also do things like Security Trimming so if a user doesn't have permission to get to the action etc it isn't displayed on the menu.

I'd check that out.